# Word.Application (Office 2016) object .quit() method hanging in LS

Tags: ms-office, lotusscript

I have a scheduled LotusScript agent that runs on a client (9.0 Social edition.)  One of its purposes is to open a Word document and save it as PDF, but that's not really important.  Here's the relevant code snippet

```
Declarations
Dim wrdApp as Variant

Sub Initialize

[Getting the usual Notes Session, Database, View values]
    Set wrdApp = createObject("Word.Application")
    wrdApp.visible = True
starthere:
    'we check to see if there is anything that has been deferred
    Set v = db.GetView("RIT")
    strStatus = "Success"

    Set doc = v.Getfirstdocument()
    If (doc Is Nothing) Then Exit Sub
[Snip]
End Sub

Sub Terminate
    wrdApp.visible = True

    Dim quitCode As Variant
    quitCode = 0
    Call wrdApp.quit(quitCode)
    Print "Quit called, waiting 3 seconds"
' Wait a couple seconds
    Sleep(3)
    Print "Done waiting, setting wrdApp to Nothing"
    Set wrdApp=Nothing
    Print "Exiting agent"
End Sub
```

The problem I'm having is that since we upgraded to Office 2016, sometimes the agent will never terminate.  In the log I see "Done waiting, setting wrdApp to Nothing" but not "Exiting agent."  I'll wind up with a Word window open (but no documents of course) and when I look in Task Manager, I see a WINWORD.EXE running with 0% CPU and 2 or 3 seconds of CPU time.  And of course just to add to the intrigue, this doesn't happen every time either.  And since the agent never ends, all other scheduled agents get held up until I kill the zombie Word instance.  I've tried all the suggestions I can find (you'll notice I make Word visible and use a Variant as the parameter to Quit, and I even threw in the sleep(3) out of desparation), but none have made any difference.  We never had this problem with Office 2010 (even when the agent code was far sloppier.)  Also, the problem can happen whether or not I actually open a Word document.  Is there a solution?  Or is going back to O2010 the only option?

Comment: Just a test: could you put all your code in the Initialize Sub? I had some bad experiences with a Terminate Sub thas was terminated before the end of the code...

Comment: This is code that I refactored a bit.  It used to set up and tear down the Word instance in a subroutine called from Initialize.  I rewrote it this way when I started having the problem (meaning it's not related to Terminate.)  While refactoring didn't help (or hurt) the problem, I like how it flows better this way.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay. I developed a wrapper class that can handle both Word and OpenOffice files "transparently". Parts of it you'll find below. I never had complaints from my client that the code no longer works, but that can also be due to the fact that they use the library to open a document using a template, then fill the document with data and then leave the document open.

One difference at first glance: I use Close where you have Quit.

-- to open a document

```
Function CreateMSWordDocument As Variant
    Dim msWord As Variant

    On Error Goto CreateNewInstance
    Set msWord = GetObject("", "Word.Application")
Done:
    Set CreateMSWordDocument = msWord
    Exit Function
CreateNewInstance:
    Print "Loading Microsoft Word.... Please Wait...."
    Err = 0
    Set msWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Print "Microsoft Word Loaded"
    Resume Done
End Function

Set wdDoc= CreateMSWordDocument
```

-- to close it again:

```
Sub Close
    Call wdDoc.Close
End Sub
```

I don't have more info for you than the above...

Comment: I use .close on the document object and .quit on the application object.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is still relevant to you.

I have used Word for ages like the way you do (just wrapping it in a Class). However, I have experienced the exact same problem...

The solution was to do *NOTHING* once I had closed the document - then the WINWORD task just silently quits in the background!

HTH
/John

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  One of the problems I also have is that Word won't always start.  I gave up and wound up taking the nuclear approach.  I wrote a .NET C# program kicked off by the scheduler that runs every 15 minutes.  If finds all running WINWORD.EXEs and if it's been running longer than 15 minutes, kills it.  In the 5 days since I've implemented it, it's killed 19 instances.

Comment: Hmmm... strange... I have no had any issues with Word not starting. And the approach above has so far worked flawlessly also in terms of stopping Word again :-)

Answer (score 0):

As a way of update/answer this question, I gave up looking for the real answer and instead wrote a C# program that looks for any instance of WINWORD.EXE that has been running for longer than 15 minutes and kill the process.  Then I use the Task Scheduler to kick that program off every 15 minutes.  It's crude and ugly, but it put out the 4-alarm fire I had before.